# django icontains to search postgres database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I currently have a Django application and postgres database. I want to have a search bar that allows users to enter in a value and it will search some of the fields of the model to search for matching values. I want this to work even for values of "". I currently have:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(myfield__icontains=search_query).order_by(...)
```

How would I make this so that it can search multiple fields of the model at the same time. What is the most efficient way to do so? Is "icontains" okay for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Q` to search multiple fields, for example:

fields that you want to search:

```
field0
field1
field2
```

Django search code:

```
from django.db.models import Q

search_result = MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(field0_icontains=search_query) |
    Q(field1_icontains=search_query) |
    Q(field2_icontains=search_query)
).order_by(...)
```

Comment: Are Django contains inefficient and bad for large quantities of data?

Comment: @CodeRocks  As I known, if you want to use `Django ORM` to complete your task, `contains` is the best choice for you, if you want to optimize your search when processing large quantities of data, I think you should use [standard DB optimization techniques](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques)

Comment: @CodeRocks I think you need a search engine like elasticsearch if you need to perform searching across multiple fields with large quantities of data. But that is out of the scope of Django...

Comment: If I had thousands of instances of models, but they were indexed in fives, would "Q" and "icontains" work fine?

Answer (score 3):

Doing this through regular filter queries and `icontains` is not advisable as it becomes inefficient pretty quickly - you certainly don't want to be doing that on multiple large text fields.

However, PostgreSQL comes with a [full text search engine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) which is designed for exactly this purpose. Django [provides support for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

You can define a [`SearchVector`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) to perform full text search on multiple fields at once, e.g., :

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('field_1') + SearchVector('field_2'),
).filter(search='search_query')
```

The documentation I've linked to provides a lot of additional information on how to perform ranking etc. on search results.

Another alternative is to use a search engine like Elasticsearch - whether this is necessary depends on how many objects you have and what kind of filtering and ranking you need to do on results.

Comment: Hi, I am able to use SearchVectors but it does not have the same flexibility as "icontains" as search results will only come up if the query matches exactly. I just want search results to come up if the model contains substrings of what they searched. How can I do this?

Comment: You probably need to look at Elasticsearch then.

Comment: Can Postgres full text search be combined with search / filtering operations on other fields? eg. can we have results be full text search for one field + `gte` condition on an int field?